# Subversion is no longer working

Tags: svn, ssl

Subversion has been fine. Today, I needed to set up SSL on the same server SVN is on, and there was an issue; both SSL and Subversion use port 433

So, in the Network tab in subversion, I changed it from port 433 to 8443

I can no longer connect to SVN. The message is

```
Unexpected HTTP Status 405 'Method not allowed'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this issue - I understand it (kind of) but not why the port change has had this affect. Any ideas what I need to do?

I've had a go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601669/svn-405-method-not-allowed but they don't seem to apply (or I don't understand them. Do I have to just re-create new directories now I've changed a port number?

Comment: First thing to test: Turn your SSL web server off, put the SVN server back on 443 - does it work again?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 you are right, it is still failing after I remove the SSL binding

Comment: You removed the SSL binding in IIs, but did you also change the SVN back to port 443? If so and it still fails, then your problem lays someplace other than the port you've chosen. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, if I have a port using SSL, does it still require to be open in the firewall? Moving back to 433 solves the issue but, I can't use 433 as SSl requries it